# R why does model.frame ignore subtractions in formula?

Tags: r

I am puzzled about formulas in R.

Say I have a formula where the right-hand side includes a transformation, like `log(var)` or `(1-var)`.

- If the transformation is the subtraction `(1-var)`, then the result of `model.frame(...)` ignores the transformed variable.
- However, if the transformation is the `log(var)`, then the result of `model.frame(...)` includes the transformed variable.

Why? Is this because the formula framework was written for linear models and subtractions lead to perfect multicollinearity? And most importantly: **How can I get variables from a formula that includes arbitrarily transformed variables in the right-hand side?**

```
dt <- data.frame(V1=1:3, V2=4:6) # sample data

fml <- V1 ~ V2 + (1-V2)
model.frame(fml, dt) # get variables --> ignores (1-V2)
#   V1 V2
# 1  1  4
# 2  2  5
# 3  3  6

# This works
fml <- V1 ~ V2 + log(V2)
model.frame(fml, dt) # get variables --> includes log(V2)
#    V1 V2  log(V2)
# 1  1  4 1.386294
# 2  2  5 1.609438
# 3  3  6 1.791759
```

**Specs**

```
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

Comment: I always find it helpful to learn not just the answer, but also where the answer was located. In this case, it is documented in `?formula`.

Comment: e.g : "While formulae usually involve just variable and factor names, they can also involve arithmetic expressions. The formula log(y) ~ a + log(x) is quite legal. When such arithmetic expressions involve operators which are also used symbolically in model formulae, there can be confusion between arithmetic and symbolic operator use.

To avoid this confusion, the function I() can be used to bracket those portions of a model formula where the operators are used in their arithmetic sense. For example, in the formula y ~ a + I(b+c), the term b+c is to be interpreted as the sum of b and c."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike log, the subtraction sign has a special meaning in the formula syntax; as a result, R is able to parse the log function, but not the subtraction sign. To regress on 1 - X, use I(1 - x), as in

```
> dt <- data.frame(V1=1:3, V2=4:6) # sample data
> 
> fml <- V1 ~ V2 + I(1-V2)
> model.frame(fml, dt)
  V1 V2 I(1 - V2)
1  1  4        -3
2  2  5        -4
3  3  6        -5
```